# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\categories() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Please I need help, I am working on a project in Laravel, I encounter a problem when T tried to use a pivot table in manay-to-many

In my `category model` `Category.php`, I have the function below

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(user::class);
}
```

In my `user model` `User.php`, I have the function below

```
public function authors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(author::class);
}
```

In `web.php`, I have this

```
Route::post('/onboarding', 'OnboardsController@categoryUser');
```

In my `onboarding view`, I have a form:

```
   <form action="{{ url('/onboarding') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
      @foreach($categories as $category)
        <div class="radio-item">
        <input class="form control" name="category_id" type="checkbox" id="category_id" required>
          <label for="name">{{ $category -> title }}</label>
        </div>
        @endforeach

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit">Proceed to Authors</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

In my `OnboardsController`

I have this

```
public function categoryUser (Request $request)
{
  $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
  $user = categories()->attach($request->input('category_id'));

  return redirect ( route ('onboarding_author')); 
}
```

This is the returned error:

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\categories()

When I change the code in my controller to

```
$category = Category::find($request->input('category_id'));
$user = User::where('user_id', Auth::id());
$category->users()->attach($user->id);
```

This is the returned error:

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\users()

Here is my full `OnboardsController.php` code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Author;
use App\User;
use App\Category;


class OnboardsController extends Controller
{
public function index()
        {
    //
    return view('onboarding')
    ->with('categories', Category::all());

}

public function author()
{
//
return view('onboarding_author')
->with('authors', Author::all());

}

public function categoryUser (Request $request)
{

    dd(request('category_id'));
    Category::findOrFail(request('category_id'))
    ->users()
    ->attach(auth()->user()->id);

    return redirect ( route ('onboarding_author')); 
}
```

Please I am new to Laravel and I have been on this for 3 days, I don't know how to solve this. I need help.

Comment: Post more code about controller. there is no clue one your sample codes.

Comment: @Gasol
Please check my edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
$user = User::findOrFail( Auth::user()->id );
$user = categories()->attach($request->input('category_id'));
   ^^^^^^
```

You are calling a method categories() on... what? on nothing. I'm assuming that you want to call the `categories()` method inside your `User.php` model. So try updating your code like this:

```
$user = User::findOrFail( Auth::user()->id );
$user->categories()->attach($request->input('category_id'));
   ^^^^^
```

This way, you will relate both objects.

---

### Side notes

As I mentioned, I'm assuming that you have the `categories` method in your `User` model:

```
# User.php

public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

Remember that models should be capitalized.

Also, you could improve your code getting the User directly from the Auth facade

This:

```
$user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
```

is the equivalente of:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

Comment: @thisiskelvin :)

Comment: I did this, but it returned 

**`SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'on' for column 'category_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `category_user` (`category_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) values (on, 2019-10-03 15:52:32, 2019-10-03 15:52:32, 1))`**

So I added timestamps to my model 
`return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->withTimestamps();`

But its still the same

Comment: Thank you, I had a problem with my form. It's working now.

Comment: @xtremeCODE glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the following:

```
public function categoryUser()
{
    Category::findOrFail(request('category_id'))
        ->users()
        ->attach(auth()->user()->id);

    return redirect(route('onboarding_author')); 
}
```

Here, you get the `Category` by the request's `category_id`, and attach the logged in user (using the `auth()` helper to get the user's `id`).

Comment: This returned error
**Call to a member function users() on null**

Comment: Is the category_id being passed? Check using `dd(request('category_id'))`

Comment: I returned 404:Not found

Comment: The error should either return null or the category id if passed correctly

Comment: It returned **null**

Comment: This means that the category_id is not being passed with the request.

Comment: It returned `'On'`, I wasn't passing the `category_id` in the form before

Comment: How are were you passing the category_id

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$category->users()->attach($user->id);

return BACK()->with('message', "message!");
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it